# How can I determine from a PowerShell script in runtime in which host it is running?

Tags: powershell

I try to figure out whether my script is running in PowerShell.exe or in the ISE. If I am running in PowerShell.exe then I would like to change the size of the console window, but I don't want to impact the ISE, if I don't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look at the `$Host` variable. The name will be "ConsoleHost" in the console and "Windows Powershell ISE Host" in the ISE. Although this can probably be a little flaky to test because you're relying on user-readable strings.

Another way might be to look at `$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Height` which seems to be always 0 in the ISE. Something which isn't very common with a console window.

Answer (score 3):

$shellid also, however a better option would be to use the separate profiles for each host:
Microsoft.PowerShell_Profile.ps1 and Microsoft.PowerShellISE_Profile.ps1. The respective files will run for the specific hosts. To run something in all hosts use the generic, Profile.ps1

Comment: `$ShellId` yields "Microsoft.Powershell" in both the console and the ISE, at least here.

Comment: Hmm, I'm used to dealing with sqlps which is the SQL 2008 host. The shellid between those hosts is different The use of separate profiles is still a possible solution.